# Let $U,V \sim R(0,1)$ be independent. Calculate $P(U \leq V)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

> Let $U,V \sim R(0,1)$ be independent. Calculate $P(U \leq V)$.

About notation: $U,V \sim R(0,1)$ mean random variables $U,V$ is equally distributed from interval $0$ to $1$.

I think there is not much to do because we have given $P(U \leq V)$, there is symmetric rule which say $$P(U \leq V) = P(V \leq U) = 0.5$$

Is this really easy like that? Or maybe that rule is not really useable here?

Comment: Do you mean Rayleigh distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's true for what you said and other reason:

$$Pr(U>V)=\int{Pr(U<v|V=v)f_V(v)dv}=\int{Pr(U<v)dF_V(v)=\int F_U(v)dF_V(v)}=\int F_U(v)dF_U(v)={{F^2_U(u)}\over{2}}|_{-\infty}^{\infty}={{1}\over{2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$P(U \leq V) = P(U-V \leq 0)$. $f_{U-V, V}(\xi, v) = f_{U,V}(\xi + v, v)\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1 \end{vmatrix}$. $U,V$ are independent by assumption, so the right side is $1$. Then $f_{U-V}(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{U-V,V}(\xi,v) dv = 1$. $-1 \leq U-V \leq 1$; so $\int_{-\infty}^{0}f_{U-V}(\xi)d\xi = \frac{1}{2} = F_{U-V}(0).$